# prerequisite to make rule with empty recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to know how to add a prerequisite to a rule with an empty recipe in GNU make. Here is a short example I made in order to explain the problem. I have a Test.c file which depends on a certain file header1.h, which includes another file header2.h. This is the make file:

```
Test : Test.c header1.h
    gcc -o Test Test.c

header1.h : header2.h
```

The last row is not empty it contains a tab character. Now assume I run make and Test is created. Afterwards I change header2.h. If I run make again, make says that Test is already updated. I expected make to remake Test since header2.h is newer than header1.h.

If I add a trivial recipe to the last rule like this

```
Test : Test.c header1.h
    gcc -o Test Test.c

header1.h : header2.h
    echo foo
```

make behaves as I expected. I also tried adding a semicolon after header2.h in the prerequisite list but this did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've told make that `Test` depends on `Test.c` and `header1.h`, so it won't run the recipe unless either of the timestamps for those two files are newer than the one for `Test`.

You could add `touch $@` as a recipe for `header1.h` but logically it doesn't really depend on the content of `header2.h`, `Test` does, so you should add `header2.h` as a dependency of `Test`.

Ideally however you'd avoid manually specifying all this and use GCC's dependency generating flags, you can also take advantage of make's built-in rules, an absolutely minimal example for something like this with a single source file would be

```
CFLAGS := -MMD
Test:
-include *.d
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is more about why make behaves differently if a dummy rule is added like touch $@. It seems like without a rule the time stamp of header1 is not changed after the rule is processed.

Comment: @Max1 `touch $@` will work because it updates the timestamp of `header1.h`, your example with `echo foo` on the other hand shouldn't behave as you wrote above, try running your makefile again making sure that only `header2.h` is newer than `Test`, you should find that `Test` is in fact not recompiled.

Comment: Thanks `touch $@` is actually exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Max1 Well as I explained in the comment if you use that precise recipe then your makefile logic is flawed, it won't make a difference for something this small but spuriously `touch`ing files is not a good idea and can lead to dependency problems and unnecessary recompilations down the road.

Comment: The file which is included by header1.h is actually not a header file, it is a set of definition for a c xmacro which I use to handle error codes. The c files using this macro only need to include the header file not the .def file. Thus I think it's appropriate to make the .def a prerequisite of the header. By using this "touch trick" I can keep the dependency centered at one place instead of specifying it for many object files. The downside is that it looks like the header file had been changed. I think this problem arises cause header1.h uses an included macro.

Comment: @Max1 "By using this "touch trick" I can keep the dependency centered at one place instead of specifying it for many object files. " If you generate dependencies automatically you won't have to use either.

Answer (score 0):

Others already provided appropriate solutions: Compiler generated dependency files.

This does not answer the part of the question, why adding a "trivial recipe" (`echo foo`) changes anything. This probably is related to the following [`make` bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?46596).

As OP already found out, the bug can be circumvented by adding a trivial recipe (eg. `@true`). This causes `make` to re-evaluate the targets' "timestamp" which is why dependencies are respected expectedly.